# Is there a lifepath system for the Star Wars setting?

Tags: character-creation, star-wars, life-paths

I'm looking for a system for generating characters similar to the system used by the MechWarrior Third Edition RPG. At each stage in a character's life from early childhood into adulthood the player chooses a path that their character is on and then rolls on a table, the result determines the nature of that portion of their life. This combination of player choice and random outcome is extremely appealing to me and I was wondering if there was anything out there similar to this but for Star Wars.

Comment: Which *Star Wars* system? Or did you want character backgrounds without mechanics?

Comment: I can always adjust the mechanics, I was more looking for background. Which system doesn't matter.

Comment: I hunted down the *MechWarrior 3* lifepath system, and it might be a good idea to include in your question why you aren't just reskinning that. (It seems pretty comprehensive and applicable.) Are you hoping someone's already reskinned it for *Star Wars*?

Comment: I'm not just reskinning it because a lot of the options are pretty specific to the battletech universe and I'm not familiar enough to translate it over.

Answer (score 2):

Bill Roper created a home-brewed character creation system for Star Wars based off of Mongoose Traveler.  It features life events, mishaps and the like.  However, it's only accessible right now with an account on the Happy Jacks RPG forums.

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted something one of my players found online for Traveller. I believe it was originally based off of the Happy Jacks material referenced by @shemake, although I'm not positive.

I have been on-again, off-again parsing it to be compatible with FFG Star Wars. I can share access to the Google drive folder if you like.

Traveller uses a 2d6 vs. difficulty check system. My method was generally that a 2d6 check of 5 correlated to a 1 purple die check, 6 to a 2 purple die check, etc. until you reached 10 where it was 1 red/4 purple. Each difficulty thereafter upgraded another die.

We played through character creation with a Force die rolled at the start of each term (a variant involved rolling 1d6 to determine the length of the term, which practically made character creation a minigame in and of itself!). That Force die determined the Destiny Point pool for the term, allowing a player/GM to upgrade the difficulty of the checks that might be required, or for the player to trade LS Points for extra event rolls in their chosen career.

This created an interesting give and take and resulted in some varied characters. I've used it a few times to develop NPCs, and while it's fun it is quite time consuming and basically serves as a stand-in for mental effort in designing NPCs.